# Yii2 форма обновления

Tags: yii2, валидация

есть форма с данными, есть одно НО, некоторые поля в ней уникальны, если их не менять, то выводится ошибка, такое поле уже существует, как это исправить?

//вид формы обновления

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'validationUrl' => \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('post/validation'),
    ]
)
?>
<?=$form->field($post, 'login')?> // уникальный логин
<?=$form->field($post, 'name')?>
<?=$form->field($post, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
<?=$form->field($post, 'email')->input('email')?> // уникальный емейл
<?=Html::submitButton('обновить', ['class'=>'btn btn-success'])?>
<?php
ActiveForm::end()
?>
```

//модель

```
class TestForm extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function rules(){ //правила валидации 
        return [
            ['login','unique','targetClass'=>'app\models\TestForm'],
            ['email','required'],
             ['email','unique','targetClass'=>'app\models\TestForm'],
            ];

    }
}
```

//контроллер

```
public function actionUpdate($id){
        $post = TestForm::findOne($id);
       if($post->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $post->save()){
        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('message', 'Обновлено');
        return $this->redirect(['index','id'=>$post->id]);
       }else{
           return $this->render('update',compact('post'));

       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Либо исправить правила валидации, чтобы указанные поля не были уникальными, либо не передавать эти поля из формы для обновления.

Comment: оба эти варианты не подходят, это получится два одинаковых логина

Comment: если их не надо изменять, то для чего их передавать в форме тогда?

Comment: а если надо? допустим человек забыл логин или емейл

Comment: Так противоречивая логика получается. Если поля уникальны, то происходит валидация, чтобы предотвратить дубли. Непонятно, что значит забыл логин?

Comment: что непонятного? есть форма на которой добавляются записи(она работает правильно), есть форма на которой редактируются, и здесь самое интересное, если не менять данные и сохранить, то валидация срабатывает, если ее отключить, то можно будет менять на значения которые уже есть в БД

Comment: Получается не надо передавать данные, если их нет необходимости изменять.